# Reducer isn't updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I can't get reducer to return updated state. It returns the updated state with correct info on 2nd time button click. `workflow` is the state which has `tasks: []`, `taskId: ''` and `hasError` variable. On button click I call `onUnassign` dispatch action which returns an error to invoke `WORKFLOW_VALIDATION_DATA_ERROR` reducer action which updates state variable `hasError` to true but `hasError` displays true on 2nd button click. I'm not able to figure it out why? Below is my code:

```
const DisActionConnected: React.FC = () => {            
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {tasks, workflow} = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.workflow);
            
  const onUnassign = () => {
    if (tasks && tasks.length > 0) {
      dispatch(setUnassign(name));
      console.log(workflow) // here hasError is true on 2nd time not first time
    }
  };
            
  return (
    <div>
      <DisActions
        userId={userId}
        onUnassign={onUnassign}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

store action

```js
export const setUnassign = (name: string) => {            
  return {
    type: TASK_UNASSIGN_PENDING,
    payload: {
      name
    }
  }
};
```

reducer function

```js
export function workflowReducer(
  state: IWorkflowState = initialState,
  action: WorkflowActionsType
): IWorkflowState {
  switch(action.type) {
    case WORKFLOW_VALIDATION_DATA_ERROR:
      return {...state, hasError: true};
    case TASK_UNASSIGN_PENDING:
      return {...state};
    default:
      return {...state};
  };
}
```

STATE

```js
export interface IWorkflowState {
  tasks: ITask[];
  taskId: string;
  hasError: boolean | null
};
        
const initialState: IWorkflowState = {
  tasks: [],
  taskId: '',
  hasError: false
};
```

```js
export function* setUnassignDis() {    
  const errorMessage = "error saving data"
  yield put({
    type: WORKFLOW_VALIDATION_DATA_ERROR,
    payload: {errorMessage} 
  });
}

function* workflowSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(WorkflowStore.TASK_UNASSIGN_PENDING, setUnassignDis);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state updates are not instantaneous and this is how Javascript [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) work. `workflow` can never be anything but what the `workflow` state value is when `onUnassign` is called. The current `workflow` value is closed over in callback scope. When the button is clicked again and the `onUnassign` callback is called it closes over the updated state from the previous update.

If you want to log updated state values then use the `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency.

Example:

```js
const {
  tasks,
  workflow
} = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.workflow);

// Log when workflow state updates
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(workflow);
}, [workflow]);

const onUnassign = () => {
  if (tasks?.length) {
    dispatch(setUnassign(name));
  }
};

...
```